# Nested contentElement by another FLUIDTEMPLATE in own extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid-styled-content

I want to write an extension that wrap a tag container around **every** type of contentElement in frontend. For instance `<div>...</div>`.

I could override the layout and template paths of fluid_styled_content and code my own html. But, what if another extension overrides my paths and use its own.

I would like to respect the recodings of those other extensions and wrap this just the same. I want to KEEP the changes the other extension did and wrap my own code additionally around.

At the moment I do this in typoscript:

```
lib.contentElement.stdWrap.wrap = <div>|</div>
```

...which works well. But that should not be the way in the age of FLUIDTEMPLATE.

What can I do? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If another extension overrides your paths, then you can configure the paths of the other extension - you are the integrator ;-) Or you choose a really high number for your path in the path chain.

Comment: @JulianHofmann thanks, but that's not the question. I want to KEEP the changes the other extension did. And wrap my own code additionally around.

Comment: Usually, in Fluid extension content is inserted via some typoscript obj using the <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="[the script]" data="{e.g. colPos:1}" />. Maybe you can wrap your div around this fluid object?